# Experience gain from green lore items

Tags: diablo-iii

Is the experience gain from the green lore items always the same, or does it vary depending on your level or difficulty setting?

I've noticed the XP gain scales upwards as I progress through the game, but I'm wondering if this is because of my characters level, the area I'm in, or if each lore item has a specific static XP amount attached to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've found, specific books / lore items have fixed experience values.

Lore items I've missed in Normal, for example, and found in Nightmare still serve up the experience I expect from Normal. At least, if I remember that correctly.

i.e. the Leah journals serve up 120xp, irregardless of level or difficulty, and other lore items you find as you progress have similar fixed values.

I think they were meant to quicken your leveling as you go through Normal and help you establish a better foothold for your character.

Comment: "Still" - So they only give XP once per character? that makes a lot of sense, thanks

Comment: I may be mistaken, but lore items I've picked up in Normal don't seem to show up in NM anymore.

Comment: Some of them can't be found in a single playthrough on Normal, and only spawn when previous books in that area have been read.